# What is going on with my ajax code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax function which calls a php page. The problem I'm getting with it, is that the error function keeps calling. What could be making the error function to call instead of the success function?

ajax:

```
function register() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/account.php",
    success: function() {
        alert("asdf");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Could not register. Please try again.");  
    },
    404: function() {
        alert("not found");  
    }
}); 
}
```

php

```
<?php
    echo "Test";
?>
```

The files are laid out into a hierarchical view looking like this:

```
index.php
js folder -> registration.js
php folder -> account.php
```

the registration.js and account.php are included into index.php so the registration.js and account.php should read as it was in the same directory as the index.php.

What am I doing wrong? :X

Comment: What happens in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) when you make the ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code but commenting out the url, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/MKc3s/

```
function register() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: "php/account.php",
        success: function() {
            alert("asdf");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Could not register. Please try again.");  
        },
        404: function() {
            alert("not found");  
        }
    });
}
register();
```

You should use Firebug in Firefox (or the Chrome console) and see what URL ajax call is calling and what error code it is reporting back.

You can also inspect the status code it returns:

```
function register() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: "php/account.php",
        success: function() {
            alert("asdf");
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert("Could not register. Please try again. Error "+xhr.status);  
        },
        404: function(xhr) {
            alert("not found");  
        }
    });
}
register();
```

In Firebug/Chrome console, you can inspect the entire object:

```
console.log(xhr);
```

Comment: Alright I had a problem in chrome it was could up on the console so fast and then go away I didn't have enough time to see it, but i managed to finally grab it and the problem was in my form action, I modified it to:

`<form action="javascript:register()" method="post">`
 and it works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that php/account.php (the url/function you're calling via ajax) is returning json, not html. Also check that the mime type is correct.

Easiest way to check: see the "Net" tab of firebug running under firefox browser.

Or use an etherpeek-like tool such as fiddler or others.

Comment: His example shows that he's not sending JSON back, and it shouldn't throw an error as is, as the documentation says it can detect what it is: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Saying that, the call should specify the type.